# prime number finding from array,c language

Tags: c

> You are given two positive integers L and R. Now print the prime
> numbers between L to R.
>
> Note: Assume that 1 is a prime number
>
> Input Format
>
> The first line will contain T, the number of test cases. Each test
> case contains two positive integer L and R Constraints
>
> 0 < T <= 20 1 <= L,R <= 100 and where L < R Output Format
>
> Print the prime numbers between L to R.

```
int main()
{
    int t, i, j;
    scanf("%d", &t);
    for (i = 0; i < t; i++) {
        int l, r;
        scanf("%d %d\n", &l, &r);

        while (l < r) {
            for (j = 2; j < l / 2; j++) {
                if (l % j != 0) {
                    printf("%d ", l);
                }
                l += 1;
            }
        }
    }
    /* Enter your code here. Read input from STDIN. Print output to STDOUT */
    return 0;
}
```

It takes input but doesnt return any value.
I tried and could not fix it. Can anyone explain what is wrong with the code? And to offer suggestions to fix it please.
Thanks.

Comment: If the numbers are really less than 100, you can use `if (i ==2 || i == 3 || i == 5 || i ==7 || ((i % 2) && (i % 3) && (i % 5)&&(i%7)))`

Comment: I'd suggest to explain to your [rubber duck](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rubber_duck_debugging) what's going on in the loop. Try it on paper.